# I don't understand android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException error in my log

Tags: android, android-resources

This is the logcat on android studio and what does it mean? If you need more informations please tell me.

```
4940-4940/werp.moodle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: werp.moodle, PID: 4940
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{werp.moodle/werp.moodle.LLandActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040039
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040039
                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:4364)
                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2372)
                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)
                                                               at werp.moodle.LLandActivity.onCreate(LLandActivity.java:52)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: 90% your activity is not in the manifest, isn't it?

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Explaining all the stuff in the log is way too long and the question is too broad.

Comment: looks like some problem with layout XML. I think that some resource set wrong way. @PierGiorgioMisley, not  a problem with manifest since it fails on `SetContentView`

Comment: Post your Activity code please

Comment: some code of the activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262261/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-unable-to-find-resource-id-0xf)

Comment: There you got the activity

Comment: @Gaetan Can you explain what you are doing here  `LLand world = (LLand) findViewById(R.id.world);
            world.setScoreField((TextView) findViewById(R.id.score));
            world.setSplash(findViewById(R.id.welcome));` what is `LLand` post ur xml

Comment: @Gaetan Please [edit] your question. Your Activity code doesn't look like  an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means it cannot find the resource it is looking for.There is no single way to fix this.First clean your project and rebuild.Sometimes when you do changes like deletion the cache in a.studio pulls out this thing an a simple cleaning can do the job .

After your clean if its still there it means that you have missing some resource  for sure.

1.First check the all relevant classes are linked to menifest

2.This error mostly occurs with an ID so if you have initialized something in your activity check those views are linked (even they linked the order is important so check the flow/if you inflate a layout please be careful)

3.Check that you have accidentally deleted a  resource like an drawable image,color code if you did, check if you still try to use those deleted ones

4.sometimes when you generate an id for a view in a run time can also pullout this error!