# Resources not found error on app termination

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, unhandled-exception

I'm experiencing this crash when I close the app from main activity.
This error doesn't show where the exception is thrown and it occurs only on app minimizing.

Anyone who have experienced this same kindly get me through this.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

```
02-06 14:55:25.929 32430-32430/com.swishpay.tab E/UncaughtException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0073
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1243)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2628)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1059)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
                                                                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                                                                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
                                                                         at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:420)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17447)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1767)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Comment: post your code here and mention in which line are error is showing. @aswin

Comment: post your resource xml and inflate code

Comment: have look [Resources$NotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274650/5110595)

Comment: @Abhishekkumar this exception is thrown in any line in my code.. it is thrown only when i come out of the app by either clicking back button or close button