# CAN not sort out :android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff

Tags: android, debugging

It's my first android application and I've an issue with an error that i couldn't sort it out.
I've done some researches in order to see similar cases such as [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262261/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-unable-to-find-resource-id-0xf) but unfortuently it doesn't help me .
Here is the debugger output :

```
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.miwok, PID: 9310
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:215)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1316)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:204)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:225)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
                      at com.example.android.miwok.WordAdapter.getView(WordAdapter.java:44)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2164)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:761)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2496)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'
```

Thanks
Here is my Adapter Class :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    LinearLayout rootitems = (LinearLayout) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.rootitems) ;
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);
    TextView defaultTranslation = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    defaultTranslation.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());
    TextView miwokTranslation = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    miwokTranslation.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTransaltion());
    ImageView icone = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.icone_miwok);
    icone.setImageResource(currentWord.getmImageResourceId());
    if (currentWord.hasImage()==true) {icone.setImageResource(currentWord.getmImageResourceId());}
    else icone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    int color= ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),mColorRessourceId);
    rootitems.setBackgroundColor(color);
    return listItemView;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `WordAdapter::getView()`?

Comment: Off course , The code is posted bellow as an answer @MichaelDodd

Comment: Right, your problem is on the line `icone.setImageResource(currentWord.getmImageResourceId());` - Can you log out the value of `currentWord.getmImageResourceId()`?

Comment: @MichaelDodd I tried to log it out with :  Log.i("NumbersActivity","Here is the ressource id "+currentWord.getmImageResourceId()); but it doesn't log anything

Comment: Are you sure? Can you double check you've not set any filters in Logcat? If not, can you try filtering logcat by the phrase `NumbersActivity`?

Comment: Unfortuently it doesn't work !! it doesn't log anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the issue to sort out the problem :
I've just to delete the first occuration of this line :

```
icone.setImageResource(currentWord.getmImageResourceId());
```

Why does it works ??
Well , it's an adapter Class that is set  in 4 other activities , one of those activities has words (elements of the ArrayList) that have not an image , by the the mImageRessourceId is -1 which is an invalid Id ressource so `icone.setImageResource(currentWord.getmImageResourceId())` will cause a crash .