# How to use setId() for imageView

Tags: android

I have an imageView created here in my GridViewAdapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    boolean checked = (mCheckBox==null)?false:(((CheckBox)  mCheckBox).isChecked());
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        //view.setTag(ViewId(), "imageViewGRID");
        view.setId(R.id.1);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
```

But I'm not sure on how to use .setId so that I can use this imageView in another class in this line:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.1);
```

Can someone please clear up how this works?

Please note that I have also tried:

```
view.setTag("imageView4Grid");
```

with

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)v.findViewWithTag("imageView4Grid");
```

but I get an error

Answer (score 3):

Heyyy, check this link: [Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714297/1739882).

From API 17 and onwards, `View` class introduced static method `generateViewId()` that will generate a value suitable for use in `setId(int)`.

`setId(int id)` simlpy takes positive integer as an input.
You are trying to fetch id from the resource. Is this what you are trying do: [How to set Id of dynamic created layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8937380/1739882)

Comment: Yeah so I created an xml file with the ids and then whenever I set the id in the one class and then try to get that view in another class, it always returns null. I asked a question on it but so far the one person who tried to answer it hasn't been responding to any feedback. Thanks for the links by the way!