# Assign a view ID programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to create a `RelativeLayout` with several children programmatically. To make the rules like `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF` work, the child views must have proper IDs.

However, when I try to assign an ID, Android Studio flags it as an error:

```
view.setId(123);

ERROR: Expected resource of type id
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it:

```
view.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Comment: Where do you set "123" as id?

Comment: I don't need `123`, I just need a new ID that doesn't conflict with an existing one.

Comment: generateViewId() requires API level 17.

Comment: so how do you use that Id later then?

Comment: `view.setId(..)` sets the view's Id to the value you got by invoking `View.generateViewId()`. That's it, you used it to assign it to your view.

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez use `view.getId()`

Comment: private int viewsCount; mEditTextDynamicTime.setTag(viewsCount);   mEditTextDynamicTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.d("position====>", String.valueOf(position));
                
            }
        });  viewsCount++;

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. This is not a compiler error. It is just editor validation error as this is not a common way to deal with Ids. So compile and run with no problems
2. Use pre-defined list of Ids with type "id" as this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937477/1657333 so the editor will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio click on lightbulb on line with this 'error'. And select 'Disable inspection' in first submenu.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, you shouldn't be using Integers directly in this case. There are some very rare cases where you might need to do this or in general suppress validation warnings. If so then you need to look into  [Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings).
In Android Studio you can click on the red light bulb at the left side of the line of code. This will show a context menu with a list of methods of suppression.