# In Eclipse, How does one specify the "android:id" for a button when creating the layout dynamically in the .java file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I looked at: [How to set Id of dynamic created layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout).

and did the following:

```
//in my .java file (in OnCreate)
submitButton.setId(R.id.dynSubmitButton);
```

in my listener method:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;
    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dynSubmitButton);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityResults12.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

I then got an error on `submitButton.setId(R.id.dynSubmitButton);` which I fixed by clicking on it and choosing `Create constant 'dynSubmitButton' in type 'id'`. I get the following error:

> [2015-01-09 14:13:18 - Application] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any integer value in setID method. But remember the following, while you set the ID.

1. Manually set ids using someView.setId(int);
2. The int must be positive.

For example, if creating and numbering several views representing items, you could use their item number.

**Example -**

```
 int i=10;
 submitButton.setId(i);
```