# Confusion with findViewById()

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to programmatically add LinearLayouts inside an existing RelativeLayout. Each LinearLayout will contain some buttons and I want to be able to toggle the visibility of each set of buttons by setting the visibility of the container LinearLayout.

```
// We iterate over a list and call the following to create the new
// layout assigning an index from a int counter
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LL.setId(nextId);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LL.setWeightSum(6f);
LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

LinearLayout mll=((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuLayout));
mll.addView(LL);
```

My problem comes when I try to retrieve these layouts later, for instance to be able to toggle their visibility on/off. I thought I would be able to use

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(layoutIndex);
```

But findViewById() gives me an error when I try to supply an int, it wants a resource ID. Is there an easy way I can convert the ints that I have assigned as the Ids for these layouts to R.id.XXX ids?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Id of dynamic created layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById(id)` looks up elements that were included as part of the XML defining a layout.

You will probably have better luck with `getChildAt(index)`, which returns the View at the passed index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Find all `LinearLayout` in a container without using ID.

```
LinearLayout mll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);//container

 for(int i=0; i<mll.getChildCount(); ++i) {
     View nextChild = mll.getChildAt(i);
     if (nextChild instanceof LinearLayout ) {
         //TODO add your code here nextChild is a LL that you wanna find
     }
 }
```