# Dynamically set id of a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have to dynamically create 4 **Buttons** and I have to generate dynamically their id, something like:

```
  for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    Button button = new Button(activity);

    // i need something here to turn this string into an int;    
    button.setId("button" + i) 
  }
```

I know how to dynamically get the id of an existing view:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("button2", "button", getPackageName())
```

What I don't know, is how to generate the id dynamically.

I looked on the internet but I didn't find in anything.

I need something like:

```
int id = getResources().setIdentifier("button2", "button", getPackageName());
button.setid(id);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `setId(int)` pass integer value as argument

Comment: why do you want to call `setId()` at all? you have the references to those `Button`s, so what do you need those IDs for?

Comment: Just play with `.setTag(string value)`. it's more useful

Comment: because, later, I need to identify by id the button I created and manipulate them

Comment: again, you have references to those views, no need for any ID

Comment: Hi @pskink, I edited my code. I don't understand how to identify the references, since the buttons are dinamically generated. There is something that I don't understand in what your are saying to me

Comment: As it was already mentioned, you have reference to button, just use .setTag(Object) to identify buttons, no need to have any ID.

Comment: Ok, I'll use setTag. Thanks to everybody :)

Comment: Related post - [How to set Id of dynamic created layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8937380/465053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `View.setId(int)` for this. According to documentation `id` need not to be unique in a tree heirarchy, you can use any (positive) Integer for the `Views`  you add programmatically.

Doc says

> The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

if you want some other info attached with the `View` you can tag objects to view using `setTag()`, and look by `findViewWithTag("obj");`

see more about creating ids here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241629/5235032

Comment: Its best practice to keep all ids unique, but its not mandatory!

Answer (score 9):

A better practice would be to use `button.setId(View.generateViewId())` which was introduced in API 17.

Answer (score 3):

1、create a xml in values folder,

2、`<resources>
    <item type="id" name="button1">123</item>
</resources>`

3、use it in java code `button.setId(R.id.button1);`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, only for ImageView.
Since I've found no answer, and everyone basically said either
 "not possible" or "use xml", I've created my own hashMap.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53321713/10295425