# How to set unique ids to Views created in a loop so that UI Automator can see them

Tags: android, android-view, android-uiautomator, programmatically-created

I have a bunch of Views added programmatically in a loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size(); j++) {
    TextView xxxView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xxx, container, false);
    xxxView.setId(k++); //this is not enough as UI Automator does not see it, id field is empty in UI Automator 
    container.addView(xxxView);
}
```

There is about 180 of those Views so it would be quite difficult to create [xml with ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout) but this may be the only solution here.

Maybe some array of ids?

Answer (score 0):

generate ids with `View.generateViewId()`

Comment: This won't work as ids are kinda random when I use View.generateViewId().

Answer (score 0):

Use something else, like *content description* or *tag*.

```
for (int j = 0; j < size(); j++) {
    TextView xxxView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xxx, container, false);
    xxxView.setId(k++); //this is not enough as UI Automator does not see it, id field is empty in UI Automator 
    xxxView.setContentDescription("id:" + k); 
    container.addView(xxxView);
}
```

Then use [UiSelector.description()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#description(java.lang.String))