# Dynamically referencing TextViews and setting Text

Tags: java, android

i am trying to get a textView id from a value from an array

I tried to use this without success:

```
String string1 = String.valueOf(token[1]);
token[0].settext(string1)
```

How do I dynamically reference a textview using an Id stored into an array?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout

Comment: no need to convert the id to String. Assuming `token` is an int array, do `((TextView)findViewById(token[0])).setText(string1);`

Answer (score 0):

***You can use this to get text***

> String string1 = token[1].getText().toString();
>       token[0].setText(string1);