# Get text from generated EditText

Tags: java, android

This code generates a new EditText each time the button is pressed

```
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ataque);

mas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText extra = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        int ntext = mispreferencias.getInt("contadortext", 0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        extra.setId(ntext);
        final int id_ = extra.getId();
        extra.setLayoutParams(p);
        editor.putInt("extra" + ntext, id_);
        editor.putInt("contadortext", ntext + 1);
        editor.commit();
        layout.addView(extra);
   }
});
```

With them already generated, I try to get the text that is written in them and save it in a SharedPreferences, but it does not work.

```
int ntext = mispreferencias.getInt("contadortext", 0);

for (int i = 0; i < ntext; i++) {
    int ide = mispreferencias.getInt("extra" + i, 0);
    EditText edi = findViewById(ide);
    editor.putString("text" + i, edi.getText().toString());
}
```

It returns the error:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Quick guess : mispreferencias.getInt("extra" + i, 0); is returning null

Comment: can you share the full code?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the definition of the `findViewById` method gives us this

```
@Nullable
public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return getWindow().findViewById(id);
}
```

Another quick look at the definition of `@IdRes` tells us this

> Denotes that an integer parameter, field or method return value is expected to be an id resource reference

Now we know that `findViewById` expects an Integer referencing a Resource.

We also know that `R` can't be modified during runtime.

We can conclude that you can't use `findViewById` for `Views` you have programatically created during runtime.

You could, but I do NOT recoment this, create a XML containing IDs as indicated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to iterate through all the EditTexts and save their texts, why don't you store them at creation in a list? So you avoid all the id trouble.

```
ArrayList<EditText> list = new ArrayList();
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ataque);

mas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText extra = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        list.add(extra);
        layout.addView(extra);
   }
});
```

now iterate through the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    editor.putString("text" + i, list.get(i).getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: I agree with your comment, but I think saving the `EditText` objects into a `Map` would suit him better, seeing as he is trying to retrieve them by ID.

Comment: Actually he does not need the id if the only he needs is store the texts in SharedPreferences. After all by having all the EditTexts in a list, he can access them by index, as he created them.