# Is there a better way to add an xml item to a linear layout so that each elements in the xml item has its own id?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to create some `CardView` items dynamically, depending on items I get via a REST call. I created a `CardView` XML layout that contains many single elements with many settings. I don't want to write this XML layout in code to create it dynamically. Is there an easy way to do this work?

Each `CardView` item has its own name etc. therefore, the IDs of the elements inside the `CardView` must be different.

Comment: have you explored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout

Comment: You should look into a RecyclerView for managing a list of items.

Comment: @TheWanderer I'll check this, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea that you take a look at this tutorial. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Basically what you want to do is create a basic CardView item, with its correspondent ViewHolder and inflate the contents of each item when you get the result from the API call.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for, thank you.